# Need help on a SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here's the scenario:

I have 3 tables in a SQL Server 2008 database - `SERVERS`, `InstalledPatches` and `Patchlist`.

The `SERVERS` table has list of servers. `InstalledPatches` has list of servers and patches installed on them. `Patchlist` has list of all patches that SHOULD be installed on each server. All patches in PATCHLIST should be ideally installed on all servers in SERVERS table. I am trying to find the patches that are missing.

**Sample data:**

**SERVERS**

```
SERVERID     SERVERNAME
----------------------- 
     1        ABC
    ..        ..
  1500        XYZ
```

**INSTALLEDPATCHES**:

```
  SERVERID  PATCHID
  -----------------
       1        1
       1        2
       2        1
      ..       ..
    1500        1
    1500        2
```

**PATCHLIST**:

```
PATCHID   PATCHNUMBER
---------------------
     1    aaa
     2    bbb
     3    ccc
     4    ddd
    ..    ..
    15    ZZZ
```

Final report should indicate missing patches:

```
SERVERID   MissingPATCHID
-------------------------
     1           3
     1           4
     1        1500
     2           3
     2           4
     2        1500
   ..
```

I have tried to use below query, but cant find all missing patches for each server.

```
SELECT 
    A.* 
FROM 
    INSTALLEDPATCHES A 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    PATCHLIST B ON A.PATCHID = B.PATCHID 
WHERE 
    A.PATCHID IS NULL
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like?

```
   select s.SERVERID, 
          pl.PATCHID MissingPATCHID
       from SERVERS s
 cross join PATCHLIST pl
      where not exists (select SERVERID, 
                               PATCHID
                          from INSTALLEDPATCHES ip
                         where ip.SERVERID = s.SERVERID 
                           and ip.PATCHID = pl.PATCHID)
```

I just created this [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c90d/2).

Comment: because there is a cross join I don't think performance will be great with big tables, but I suspect you don't have huge amount (millions?) of servers or patches :)

Comment: @mucio - thanks for the answer. Can you please tell me if my answer is okay too. Is there any problem with it.

Comment: @mucio - I am getting an error in your query. Can you please help me -An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','. Thanks.

Comment: Mucio, looks like I spoke too soon. The above query gives syntax error in SQL.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev probably old versions of SQLServer weren't supporting this kind of syntax(http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299231/add-support-for-ansi-standard-row-value-constructors)

Comment: I wrote the answer without knowing that SQL Server was so bad to implement the SQL standard :) I hope my new answer will work now

Comment: @Akshay - If my answer work for you, then please upvote even if you not select it. Btw, Mucio answer works now.

Comment: I have created a SQLFiddle demo to show the results, I tested it and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Try my query. It works now.

```
select s.serverid, p1.patchid as MissingPatchID 
from [servers] as s
left join patchlist as p1
on 1=1
left join installedpatches as p2
on s.serverid = p2.serverid
and p1.patchid = p2.patchid
where p2.patchid is null
```

Comment: Borat, the only problem is this doesnt return patches present on few servers but not on others.

SAMPLE TABLE DATA:
#SERVERS
serverid
--------
a
b

#INSTALLEDPATCHES
serverid patchid
-------- -------
a        1
a        2
b        1
a        4

#PATCHLIST
patchid
-------
1
2
3
4


OUTPUT OF QUERY:
serverid MissingPatch
-------- ------------
a        3
b        3



Missing data:
serverid MissingPatch
-------- ------------
b        4

Comment: @Akshay - i am not able to understand. Please tell me in more detail.

Comment: I have created a SQLFiddle demo (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c90d/2). @BoratSagdiyev this query doesn't work correctly if a server is associated to no patches.

Comment: @Akshay - my bad. forgot to add condition to join on server as well. It is working correctly now.

Comment: @mucio - thanks for your answer and help. I like you.